# Умножить все значения с одни классом jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите пожалуйста, как умножить все значения span с определенным классом?

```html
<span class="cost">10</span>
<span class="cost">20</span>
<span class="cost">30</span>
<span class="cost">40</span>
```

Comment: Умножить на какое число ?

Comment: @Demon__ANT просто перемножить эти числа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К примеру так. (UPD. + на JQuery)

```js
// JS
var costs = document.querySelectorAll('.cost');
var resultCont = document.querySelector('.result');
var result = Object.keys(costs).reduce(function(inc, current) {
  return inc * parseInt(costs[current].innerText);
}, 1);
resultCont.innerText = result;

//JQ

var $costs = $('.cost');
var resultCont = $('.result2');
var result2 = 1;
$costs.each(function(index, item) {
  result2 *= parseInt($(item).text());
})

resultCont.text(result2);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="cost">10</span>
<span class="cost">20</span>
<span class="cost">30</span>
<span class="cost">40</span>
<br>
Результат: 
<span class="result"></span>

<br>
Результат JQuery: 
<span class="result2"></span>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: @ВладиславСамохин пожалуйста. Прикрепил результат на JQuery еще

Answer (score 0):

```js
let elemArray = document.querySelectorAll('.cost');
let sum = Array.from(elemArray).reduce((s, c) => {
 return s * +c.textContent
}, 1);
console.log(sum);
```

```html
<span class="cost">10</span>
<span class="cost">20</span>
<span class="cost">30</span>
<span class="cost">40</span>
```